# how to retrieve value from url in flask

Tags: python, flask, get, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have developed a web app using flask, jinja template and bootstrap. I want to retrieve the name of the user from the URL after login and show it in the dashboard. After logging in it is showing the name. But when I click the dashboard it shows 'none' because the name is getting removed from the URL. If there is any solution to it tell me. It will be very helpful. Thanks in advance. The codes are given below.

app.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    name=form.name.data

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if user.password == form.password.data:
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                session['logged_in'] = True
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard', name=name))

        return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    name=request.args.get('name')
    return render_template('dashboard.html',name=name)
```

dashboard.html

```
<section id="home" style="background: url('../static/images/rate25.jpg');background-attachment: fixed;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;">
        <div class="container-fluid con" align="center">
            <div class="row" align="center">
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h1 class="h1" style="font-weight: 500;text-transform: unset;">Hi {{name}}, Welcome to Ratingspro</h1></div>
               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

After Logging in I am getting this
[image: dashboard]

After clicking the dashboard in navbar I am getting this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What do you get in the console if you modify the code like:

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    name=request.args.get('name')
    print('name: {}'.format(name)) 
    return render_template('dashboard.html',name=name)
```

If you get nothing it means the name is not passed via 'args'. It may be passed by other method like request.data, request.json, request.form